# Predicted features combined with original ones

Tags: predictive-modeling

I am currious  how good  such  a procedure could be :
I  get some predictions  of some 10  learners  trained   on train set  and predicted on train set also .
Then I am column binding   those predictions  to the original train.
Could this  be  a valid procedure  on improving  learning process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This procedure exists and is called *stacked generalization* or simply *stacking*. See stacking section from [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). Strating from there you can red more by following references from the page. The first paper on subject was published by Wolpert in 1992.

[Later edit]

Do not combine the results with original features, but keep only the predictions combined only with the target.

Comment: Tryied  stacking  before  , we  talked  on  a   previous thread about this, hence  it  is  not  always  improving   ,  I  arrived at this question